# How to change the model of a mat-select in NgRx Store

Tags: angular-material, ngrx, ngrx-store

This is my template:

```
<mat-select [ngModel]="selected3">
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="handleChange($event,srs.id)" *ngFor="let srs of schemas" [value]="srs.id">
        {{srs.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In `handleChange()` the state of the variable `selected3` is updated in NgRx store, but in my option it is not selected in mat-select drop-down. If I remove this `(onSelectionChange)` event, i.e. not dispatching a store action through `handleChange`, option selection works. I don't know what's going wrong here.

Comment: Do you use Observables to access the NgRx store?

Comment: @SanthoshV I have tried [(ngModel)] but not working

Comment: Use `(selectionChange)` event inside `<mat-select>` tag instead of `(onSelectionChange)`.

Comment: @SparkFountain Yes I'm using Observables but the problem is, when mat-select try to change the model value, Store don't allow to do that, as its read only value for UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="handleChange($event.value)" [ngModel]="selected3">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let srs of schemas" [value]="srs.id">
      {{srs.name}}
    </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

Use `(selectionChange)` event inside `<mat-select>` tag instead of `(onSelectionChange)`;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing [(ngModel)] with [value] as we have a read only value for mat-select which will be modified in the NgRx store.

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="handleChange($event)"
                    [value]="selected3?.id">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let srs of schemas" [value]="srs.id">
                        {{srs.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
```

What I need in handleChange() is id of currently selected srs, which I get by $event.value